# Tengo el siguiente error al tratar de validar un inicio de sesión en PHP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

```
<?php
session_start();
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$contrasena=$_POST['contrasena'];

//conectar a la base

$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "project");
$consulta="SELECT * FORM login WHERE usuario='$usuario' and contrasena='$contrasena'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
if($filas>0){
    header("location:bienvenido.html");
}
else{
    echo "Error en la autenticación";
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);


    ?>
```

[image: Pero me salen los siguientes errores:]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Comment: tienes mal escrita tu consulta es SELECT * FROM y tu pusiste SELECT * FORM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te saludo y te comento que el error se esta presentando por una sintáxis errónea, lo cual se presenta en esta línea

```
$consulta="SELECT * FORM login WHERE usuario='$usuario' and contrasena='$contrasena'";
```

Tienes mal escrito el `FROM` pues pusiste `FORM`

Dado lo anterior deberás corregirlo del modo siguiente

```
$consulta="SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario='$usuario' and contrasena='$contrasena'";
```

Al momento es los detalles que observo de encontrar mas actualizaré la respuesta

Comment: capo un abrazo, tenias razón, ya me conecta. muchas gracias saludos maquina

Answer (score 1):

Te dejare un breve ejemplo:

```
    //conectando a mysql
    $mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'tu_usuario', 'tu_clave', 'tu_base');
   //en caso de error
  if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
  echo "Error: Fallo al conectarse a MySQL debido a: \n";
  echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->connect_errno . "\n"; 
  exit;
  }
```

ahora vamos con una consulta se realiza asi:

```
// Realizar una consulta SQL
$sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario = $usuario";
if (!$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
 // cómo obtener información del error
echo "Error: La ejecución de la consulta falló debido a: \n";
echo "Query: " . $sql . "\n";
echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->errno . "\n";
echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error . "\n";
exit;
 }
//validando el resultado
if ($resultado->num_rows === 0) {
 echo "Usuario incorrecto !!";
 exit;
 }else{
 //redirigue a donde desees..
 header("location:bienvenido.html");
 }
 //liberar el resultado y cerrará la conexión
 $resultado->free();
 $mysqli->close();
```

Espero te sea de utilidad !!

[Documentacion Oficial Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli.php)

Comment: gracias por el dato amigo, lo tomare en cuenta. un abrazo (y)